# Nginx solo muestra mi pagina index.html

Tags: nginx

Tengo 2 servidores nginx configurados,el primero es un proxypass y en el segundo tengo mi pagina web y demás servicios.

El problema es que únicamente me muestra el index.html , cuando intento acceder a otras paginas .html o .php me dice que no encuentra la pagina.

```
   server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/proyecto;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name www.proyectoasir.es;
location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.0.100;
        }
        location ~ \.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.100;
        }
        location /somedirectory/ {
    autoindex on;
}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                #With php7.0-cgi alone:
                #fastcgi_pass 192.168.0.100:9000;
                # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.0.100;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

debes de agregar el siguiente parametro en proxy_pass **$request_uri**

El cual tu configuracion quedaria asi:

ACTUAL:

```
location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.100;
        }

        location ~ \.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.100;
        }
        location /somedirectory/ {
        autoindex on;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                #With php7.0-cgi alone:
                #fastcgi_pass 192.168.0.100:9000;
                # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.0.100;
}
```

MOFICICADO:

```
location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.100$request_uri;
            }
            location ~ \.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$ {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.100$request_uri;
            }
            location /somedirectory/ {
        autoindex on;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    #With php7.0-cgi alone:
                    #fastcgi_pass 192.168.0.100:9000;
                    # With php7.0-fpm:
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.100$request_uri;
    }
```

Saludos.